# In Code first The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, sql, database, code-first

I just started using Code first approach for creating databases. I have following 3 tables :

```
public partial class AccountHolder
{
    public int AccountHolderId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Address> Address { get; set; }
}

public partial class Nominee
{
    public int NomineeId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Address> Address { get; set; }
}

public partial class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    public int AccountHolderId { get; set; }
    public AccountHolder AccountHolder { get; set; }

    public int NomineeId { get; set; }
    public Nominee Nominee { get; set; }
}
```

Here `AccountHolder` and `Nominee` both have `1 to *` replationship with the address. The fluent API code which i used for this is :

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasRequired(p => p.AccountHolder)
                                      .WithMany(p => p.Address)
                                      .HasForeignKey(p => p.AccountHolderId)
                                      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasRequired(p => p.Nominee) 
                                      .WithMany(p => p.Address)
                                      .HasForeignKey(p => p.NomineeId)
                                      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

Now my issue is whenever i am trying to insert data in AccountHolder or Nominee i got this exception :

*In case of AccountHolder insertion*

> {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.Addresses_dbo.Nominees_NomineeId\". The conflict occurred in database \"CodeFirst.BankContext\", table \"dbo.Nominees\", column 'NomineeId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

*In case of Nominee insertion*

> {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.Addresses_dbo.AccountHolders_AccountHolderId\". The conflict occurred in database \"CodeFirst.BankContext\", table \"dbo.AccountHolders\", column 'AccountHolderId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Cananybody please tell me how to solve this issue and what i am missing here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try to insert Address Nominees_NomineeId that is not exists in  Nominee.You should First instance of Nominee then fill value  and create Address and fill value last create instance of AccountHolder.and then save

Comment: Thanks for answer, it works. But now whenever i will insert nominee or accountholder, i have to create an empty object for nominee in case of accountholder insertion and an empty object for accountholder in case of nominee insertion, is there any way by which i can set the default values for both of these navigational properties ?

Comment: I think u should insert value and then use it for example u must insert value in table and then use it.

Comment: ok, but just for curiosity whats the problem with setting default values for both ?

Comment: For example i have tow table manager and person.and each manager as a person so you want insert in manager that person id is 1 but person that has 1 id is not exist and get error

Answer (score 1):

In your table dbo.AccountHolders and dbo.Nominees, it has a foreign key reference to another table. The way a FK works is it cannot have a value in that column that is not also in the primary key column of the referenced table.

If you have SQL Server Management Studio, open it up and sp_help 'dbo.dbo.Nominees'. See which column that FK is on, and which column of which table it references. You're inserting some bad data.Do the same for sp_help 'dbo.dbo.AccountHolders '.

Hope this helps.