# Issue with 1 to many relationship through code first

Tags: c#, sql, code-first

I just asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185991/in-code-first-the-insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint/15186039#15186039) and got the solution also, but the solution creates a new issue which i am mentioning here. Here i modify my code and creates a new 1 to 1 relation between `AccountHolder` and `Nominee`.

```
public partial class AccountHolder
{
    public int AccountHolderId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Address> Address { get; set; }
    public virtual Nominee Nominee { get; set; }
}

public partial class Nominee
{
    public int NomineeId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Address> Address { get; set; }
}

public partial class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }    

    public int AccountHolderId { get; set; }
    public AccountHolder AccountHolder { get; set; }

    public int NomineeId { get; set; }
    public Nominee Nominee { get; set; }
}
```

The relationship between them are as follows :

```
  1 to many between AccountHolder and Address
  1 to many between Nominee and Address
  1 to 1 between AccountHolder and Nominee
```

The fluent Api code for this is :

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<AccountHolder>().HasOptional(p => p.Nominee)
                                            .WithRequired()
                                            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasRequired(p => p.AccountHolder)
                                      .WithMany(p => p.Address)
                                      .HasForeignKey(p => p.AccountHolderId)
                                      .WillCascadeOnDelete();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasRequired(p => p.Nominee)
                                      .WithMany(p => p.Address)
                                      .HasForeignKey(p => p.NomineeId)
                                      .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Firstly if there is any scope of improvement than please suggest me. Now the problem which i am facing here is whenever i insert `AccountHolder` i have to create a empty instance of `Nominee` and while inserting `Nominee` i have to create empty instance of `AccountHolder`. And if i will not do this than the error occurred which i have mentioned on my previous question. Can anybody please guid me how i can solve this issue, please add the example code in your solution.

*Code i am using for inserting data is :*

```
var accountHolder = new AccountHolder() { 
                      AccountHolderId = 901, 
                      Address = new List<Address>() 
                      { 
                        new Address() 
                        { 
                          HouseNumber = hnumber, 
                          Street = street, 
                          Nominee = new Nominee() //this is the issue
                        } 
                      }, 
                      Nominee = new Nominee() 
                      {  
                          Address = new List<Address>() 
                          {
                             new Address() 
                             { 
                               HouseNumber = n_hnumber, 
                               Street = n_street, 
                               AccountHolder = new AccountHolder() //this is the issue
                             } 
                          } 
                       } 
};
```

---

Thanks!

Comment: hey I tried you code. and added a new accountholder, providing just the accountHolderId, and it worked for me. btw, logically your classes and relationship are wrong, syntactically they are right though

Comment: the issue will occure when you insert Address for accountholder and can you please tell me what is wrong in my classes logic ?

Comment: that's because, your address table has required dependency on two FKs, AddressId and NomineeId. Any entry to the address table will require these two first. so you have to enter Nominee and Address both for either of them

Comment: logically, Address should always be independent, your AccountHolder and nominee should  be dependent upon Address and not the other way round. otherwise, you will have to do wat you are doing now, create all the entities objects to suffice one

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally i got the solution, but if there a better solution than please suggest me. What i did is create the FKs in Address table optional (nullable) :

*Change in classes :*

```
public partial class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }    

    public int? AccountHolderId { get; set; }
    public AccountHolder AccountHolder { get; set; }

    public int? NomineeId { get; set; }
    public Nominee Nominee { get; set; }
}
```

*change in fluent api :*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AccountHolder>().HasOptional(p => p.Nominee)
                                            .WithRequired()
                                            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasOptional(p => p.AccountHolder)
                                      .WithMany(p => p.Address)
                                      .HasForeignKey(p => p.AccountHolderId)
                                      .WillCascadeOnDelete();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasOptional(p => p.Nominee)
                                      .WithMany(p => p.Address)
                                      .HasForeignKey(p => p.NomineeId)
                                      .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Answer (score -1):

as far as I understant your needs, the following runs.

Note that setting the AccountHolderId is a bit hard because, with the one to one relation with nominee, the PK of Nominee is also a FK.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace testEF {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            using ( EFContext efc = new EFContext() ) {
                var AHAddress = new Address {
                    AddressId = 1,
                    HouseNumber = "150",
                    Street = "street",
                };
                var AHNominee = new Nominee {
                    NomineeId = 1,
                    Address = new List<Address>() { 
                        AHAddress
                    }};                
                var accountHolder = new AccountHolder() {
                    Address = new List<Address>() { 
                        AHAddress
                    },
                    Nominee = AHNominee
                };
                efc.Holders.Add(accountHolder);
                efc.SaveChanges();

                foreach (AccountHolder ah in efc.Holders) {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", ah.AccountHolderId, ah.Nominee.NomineeId);
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public partial class AccountHolder {
        public int AccountHolderId { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Address> Address { get; set; }
        public virtual Nominee Nominee { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Nominee {
        public int NomineeId { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Address> Address { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Address {
        public int AddressId { get; set; }

        public String HouseNumber { get; set; }
        public String Street { get; set; }

        public int AccountHolderId { get; set; }
        public AccountHolder AccountHolder { get; set; }

        public int NomineeId { get; set; }
        public Nominee Nominee { get; set; }
    }


    public class EFContext : DbContext {
        public IDbSet<AccountHolder> Holders { get; set; }

        public EFContext()
            : base() {
            Database.SetInitializer<EFContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EFContext>());
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<AccountHolder>().HasOptional(p => p.Nominee)
                                            .WithRequired()
                                            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasRequired(p => p.AccountHolder)
                                          .WithMany(p => p.Address)
                                          .HasForeignKey(p => p.AccountHolderId)
                                          .WillCascadeOnDelete();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasRequired(p => p.Nominee)
                                          .WithMany(p => p.Address)
                                          .HasForeignKey(p => p.NomineeId)
                                          .WillCascadeOnDelete();
        }
    }    
}
```